# Make a new dataframe by groupby and apply own function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as following.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'],
    'budget': [100, 150, 200, 250, 200, 200]})
```

```
   id   date    budget
0   1   2020-01-01  100
1   2   2020-01-01  150
2   2   2020-01-02  200
3   2   2020-01-03  250
4   3   2020-01-01  200
5   3   2020-01-02  200
```

How can I efficiently transform the dataframe into a new dataframe with the following output assuming that today is `2020-01-04`?

```
    id  total_budget    budget_2_days_ago
0   1   100 NaN
1   2   600 200
2   3   400 200
```

```
def is_two_days_ago(date):
    return datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=2) == date
```

What I tried is making a dataframe that contains unique ids first then putting sum and apply function detecting the budget 2 days ago one by one but I don't feel it is a good way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it. A function is not needed.

```
from datetime import timedelta
a = '2020-01-04'
b = pd.to_datetime(a, format = '%Y-%m-%d')-timedelta(days=2)
consolidated = df.groupby('id')['budget'].sum().reset_index(name='total_budget')
days_ago = df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')== b].groupby('id')['budget'].sum().reset_index(name='budget_2_days_ago')
consolidated.merge(days_ago, on='id', how='left')
```

**output**

```
    id  total_budget    budget_2_days_ago
0   1   100             NaN
1   2   600             200.0
2   3   400             200.0
```

Comment: Exactly what I would do.